# Securing and encrypting connection between Client and Server

Tags: php, security, networking, ssl

I want to send very sensitive data to a webserver by calling a specific php file with data over `GET` or `POST` (not sure yet). The data contains 3 values, so I thought of building an own algorithm, but this could be reverseengineered easily and I guess there are far better solutions than those I have.

The difficulty is basically this: When a user buys a inapp purchase for a Windows App he gets access to this server. MS does not offer any OAUTH check like Google does so developers have to implement their own check. Also we don't have any user accounts.

Do you have any ideas on how to restrict users that haven't bought the purchase from accessing this server php file (which is secure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of 'handshaking' methods you could use. One method that has worked for me:

1. Open the channel to your server
2. Server sends a string of random characters to the client
3. Client hashes the string with a known salt and sends this string back to the server
4. Server compares the returned string with it's own encrypted version of the original string
5. If they match then the client session is allowed

This prevents someone from doing a `replay` attack on your server.

If you want to stick with a typical 'web transaction' then use HTTPS (port 443) to handle your encryption. Another alternative would be to use an encrypted socket to a different port.

Comment: That is a very good solution! However it only works if the client source can not be decompiled, but it is okay for my purpose! THANK YOU!